# Javascript: parseJSON mutiple values coming up undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, syntax, syntax-error

So I have something along the lines of the following:

```
"facet_counts": {
    "facet_pivot": {
        "nodeOne,nodeTwo": [
```

I am trying to create a variable in Javascript to call this that looks something like this:

```
      var test = $.parseJSON(data).facet_counts.facet_pivot.nodeOne,nodeTwo;
```

However this array will be `undefined`. I think the cause will be a result of `nodeOne,nodeTwo`. Does anybody know the correct syntax to write the VAR?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var test = $.parseJSON(data).facet_counts.facet_pivot["nodeOne,nodeTwo"];
```

since a variable name cannot have a `comma` `,`